# How to access to an specific policy on shop.policies

Tags: shopify, liquid

im creating a individual template for each policy on site, how can i show only that specific policy on each template, here is code i made for that:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center my-8">
  {% for policy in shop.policies %}
    <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold tracking-tighter my-4 md:my-8">{{ policy.title }}</h1>
    <div class="py-2 mb-4 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-xs font-semibold tracking-tighter">
      <span class="mr-2">
        {{ 'general.last_updated' | t }}
      </span>
      {{ policy.published_at | date: '%d/%B/%Y' }}
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-4">{{ policy.body }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

i tried to access on policy object with handle filter like:

```
{{ policy['terms-of-service'].title }}
```

but it doesn't work, anyone is able to guide me how can i get it works?
thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

here is code i have at the moment, with [shop.privacy_policy] but make an loop with that creating 2 policies on section.

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center my-8">
  {% for policy in shop.policies %}
    <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold tracking-tighter my-4 md:my-8">{{ shop.privacy_policy.title }}</h1>
    <div class="py-2 mb-4 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-xs font-semibold tracking-tighter">
      <span class="mr-2">
        {{ 'general.last_updated' | t }}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto px-4">{{ shop.privacy_policy.body }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and some image to show what i mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an objet for each policy inside shop.

`shop.privacy_policy`
`shop.refund_policy`
`shop.shipping_policy`
`shop.subscription_policy`
`shop.terms_of_service`

Check this: https://www.shopify.ca/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet

Comment: thanks for your answer, did you mean something like this? {% for policy in shop.privacy_policy.policies %}

Comment: No there is only one policy under `privacy_policy` so it's more like `shop.privacy_policy.body`

Comment: okay, i edited original post with code i have at the moment, i changed policy.body to shop.privacy_policy.body and now i get just that policy, but it show 2 time's on page..

Comment: In the question you say you want to visualize a specific policy. You don't need any for cycle for that.

Comment: thanks it works, just removing for cycle, and that's it :)